# How does the '--p' work in for(p=&(*L).elem[(*L).length-1];p>=q;--p)?

Tags: c++, c, loops, for-loop, decrement

I am trying to debug the following code:

```
Status ListInsert_Sq(SqLIst *L, int i, LElemType_Sq e)
{
    LElemType_Sq *newbase;
    LElemType_Sq *p, *q;

    if(i<1 || i>(*L).length+1)
        return ERROR;                   
    if((*L).length >= (*L).listsize)
    {
        newbase = (LElemType_Sq*)realloc(LElemType_Sq *)realloc((*L).elem, ((*L).listsiz+LISTINCREMENT)*sizeof(LElemType_Sq));
        if(!newbase)
            exit(OVERFLOW);

        (*L).elem = newbase;
        (*L).listsize += LISTINCREMENT; 
     } 

     q = &(*L).elem[i-1];
     for(p=&(*L).elem[(*L).length-1];p>=q;--p)
        *(p+1) = *p;

    *q = e;
    (*L).length++;

    return OK;
}
```

Is using `--p` correct here? 
Specifically I wonder if the last element of the list is going to be moved or overwritten by the previous element?

Thank you!

Comment: `*(p+1) = *p` is an error because there is no semicolon after it.

Comment: The nested `realloc()` is beyond recognition.

Comment: Debugging source like this is a punishment exercise.  Please stop writing 'clever', (undebuggable), code:(

Comment: Minor grammar corrections to make your question more clear. Added more tags

Comment: There's a reason `->` exists in the language -- you should use it as it makes code like this much more readble.  Though I would guess this code is actually the output of some kind of machine translation from some other language...

Answer (score 1):

This code (in which I have added the missing semicolon):

```
for(p=&(*L).elem[(*L).length-1];p>=q;--p)
    *(p+1) = *p;
```

sets `p` to point to the last assigned element in the array `elem`. Then `*(p+1) = *p;` copies this last set element to the newly allocated space (allocated with `realloc`) above. (By “assigned element”, I mean one for which a value had been assigned.)

Then `--p` decrements the pointer to point to the previous element. (Using arithmetic on pointers works in units of array elements.) Then `*(p+1) = *p;` copies the second-to-last assigned element to the previous space of the last assigned element. Then the loop continues on this way, effectively moving each element one further space up the array.

Ultimately, the loop appears to be intended to stop when the element with index `i-1` has been moved, as `q` is set to the address of that element with `q = &(*L).elem[i-1];`.

However, it is defective. If `i` is one, then `q` points to the first element of the array, and `p` will eventually reach that element, and `--p` will attempt to decrement `p` to point before the start of the array. The behavior of this attempt is not defined by the C standard. (This presumes `L` points to the start of the array. It is possible `L` points into an array beyond its start, in which case this problem does not occur.)

Comment: The code does being with an `if (i<1) return ERROR` test, so it seems like having i=0 at the point in question is impossible...

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Thanks. My text should have said “If `i` is one” rather than “If `i` is zero”. I have corrected it. If `i` is one, which is permitted by the initial screen, then `q` points to element 0 of the array, since it is set with `i-1`. Then `p` will be decremented before that element, which is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

After rewriting,the *guessed* intention of the code looks like:

---

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "listmeuk.h"

Status ListInsert_Sq(SqLIst *lp, int index, LElemType_Sq elem)
{
    if(index<1 || index>lp->length+1) return ERROR; // this assumes 1-based indexing
    index--; // transform to zero-based indexing

    if(lp->length >= lp->listsize)
    {
        LElemType_Sq *newbase;
        newbase = realloc(lp->elem, (lp->listsiz+LISTINCREMENT) *sizeof *newbase);
        if(!newbase) exit(OVERFLOW);

        lp->elem = newbase;
        lp->listsize += LISTINCREMENT; 
     } 

    if(index < lp->length) memmove(&(lp->elem[index+1]), &(lp->elem[index]), (lp->length-index) * sizeof lp->elem[0] );

    lp->elem[index] = elem;
    lp->length++;

    return OK; 

}
```